# Javascript/jQuery if statement not comparing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm quite new to using jQuery with Javascript and I've got a bug where I need to analyse every part of a pre-written function.

Part of this function includes an if statement seemingly without a condition and I was hoping someone would be able to explain it to me, code below.

```
$("a").bind("click", myFunction);

function myFunction(event) {
        if (event.target) {
       // some code
    }
}
```

My confusion here is what "if (event.target)" is equating to/testing as it is doesn't seem to be comparing anything. Any help or pointing towards reading material would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please share you code.

Comment: A mouse click is an event. The document object model (DOM) element you just clicked on is the target.

Comment: _"As of jQuery 3.0, `.bind()` has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7"_

Comment: It's due to the type coercion that JS does. Sometimes it's helpful, sometimes its a pain that you need to be aware of. See this: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: it's just checking if the event.target property of the event object will be null or not

Comment: what you want to compare

Comment: `bind()` is used to place an event on a dom element. `myFunction` is called when you click in a `a` element. Then ` if (event.target)` checks if the dom element you clicked existe. But this test is useless beacause the method `myFunction` is called when you click.

Comment: Thanks Rory and Roljhon, I'll give that article a read through. So it is safe to say in Javascript that "if (someVariable)" is basically the same as "if (someVariable != null)"?

Comment: Yes, or `(someVariable != null && someVariable != undefined && someVariable != '' ...)` etc.

Comment: Perfect! That makes sense and that article is really clearing it up, thanks a lot!

Comment: Just be careful with truthy and falsy values as they can represent traps in the code. Personally, I prefer getting verbose conditions ensuring a determined value in most cases. But when you are sure a variable is a boolean (for example), the coercion remains an easy to read and friendly condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any condition can be tested as 'falsy' or 'truthy'.

For exemple :

```
const iAmTruthy = true;
if (iAmTruthy) {
  console.log('the condition is fulfilled');
}
```

Here's a list of truthy values in JS : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Here's another example with falsy value :

```
const iAmTruthy = false;
if (!iAmTruthy) {
  console.log('the condition is fulfilled');
}
```

And a list of falsy values : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is comparing the `event.target`. It will return `true` if the variable have some value (and has been defined), otherwise it will return `false`.

*Note: `false`, `0`, `''`, or `null` will return `false` too.*

```js
var a; //undefined
if(a){ console.log('undefined a: true'); } else { console.log('undefined a: false'); }

a = null;
if(a){ console.log('null a: true'); } else { console.log('null a: false'); }

a = 0;
if(a){ console.log('zero a: true'); } else { console.log('zero a: false'); }

a = '';
if(a){ console.log('empty string a: true'); } else { console.log('empty string a: false'); }

a = 1;
if(a){ console.log('number a: true'); } else { console.log('number a: false'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to jQuery, and just plain JavaScript.

The if statement condition is an expression that in the end evaluates to true or false. This can be an explicit comparison like `a===b`, but you can also evaluate other values that are considered to be true or false by the if statement. You're testing whether they are 'truthy' or 'falsy'.

In this particular case, you're basically testing if `event.target` has something assigned to it. If it has, it is truthy, otherwise it is falsy. The unwritten assumption is that if it has, it's a valid DOM element.

It's unlikely that something else was assigned to event.target, so this code just loosely checks if *something* is there or not, rather than checking explicitly whether that something is indeed a valid element and not, say, `15` or `'Hello world'`. These kinds of assumptions are pretty common, because otherwise your code will become slow and hardly readable because of all the checks.

See Mozilla to learn more about ['truthy'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and ['falsy'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).